# Estimating size of greatest prime divisor of a sequence of integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, asymptotics

Consider the numbers of the form: $$A_n = \prod_{\pm}\left(\pm 1\pm \sqrt{2} \pm \cdots \pm \sqrt{n}\right)$$

where, the product in taken oven all $2^n$ terms with variations in sign. We know such numbers are integers (even perfect-squares).

> Is there a way to investigate the asymptotics of the largest prime divisor of $A_n$?

Source: [Problem A-578](http://www.komal.hu/verseny/feladat.cgi?a=honap&h=201301&t=mat&l=en) where it was claimed that that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $n_0$ such that for every $n>n_0$ the largest prime divisor of $A_n$ is smaller than $\displaystyle 2^{2^{\,\huge{\varepsilon} n}}$. I haven't been able to prove this claim either.

Comment: You could try calculating the first few terms and then consulting the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $A_n$ seem to be closely related to [Swinnerton Dyer Polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Swinnerton-DyerPolynomial.html).

Comment: Not all that closely, since they involve only square roots of primes, whereas $A_n$ involves all square roots.

Comment: @PietroMajer $A_n = \prod_{\pm}\left(1\pm \sqrt{2} \pm \cdots \pm \sqrt{n}\right)^2$

Comment: I would consider the sequence of polynomials $P_0(x)=x$, $P_n(x)=P_{n-1}(x-\sqrt{n})P_{n-1}(x+\sqrt{n})$, that have $P_n(0)=A_n$

Comment: @Gerry Myerson indeed it gives https://oeis.org/A262396

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sequence grows too rapidly and I doubt that one can get meaningful asymptotics for the largest prime factor.  However, one can show that the largest prime factor is bounded by $(n\sqrt{n})^{2^{\pi(n)}}$ where $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes up to $n$, and since $\pi(n) \sim n/\log n$, this implies a stronger bound than what you wanted.

To see this, put $\alpha =1+ \sqrt{2} + \ldots + \sqrt{n}$ and let $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)$ be any choice of signs.  Set $\epsilon(\alpha)= \sum_{j=1}^{n} \epsilon_j \sqrt{j}$.  Note that $\alpha$ and all the $2^n$ values $\epsilon(\alpha)$ all belong to the field $K={\Bbb Q}(\sqrt{p}, 2\le p\le n)$ which has degree $2^{\pi(n)}$ and Galois group $H \simeq ({\Bbb Z}/2)^{\pi(n)}$. Note that the choice of all possible signs $\epsilon$ forms a group $G \simeq ({\Bbb Z}/2)^n$, and $H$ may be thought of as a subgroup of $G$ in the obvious way.  Then 
$$ 
A_n = \prod_{\epsilon \in G/H} N_K(\epsilon(\alpha)), 
$$ 
where the product is over the $2^{n-\pi(n)}$ cosets $G/H$, and $N_K$ is the norm in $K$ (the product over all the elements of $H$).  Note that all the $N_K(\epsilon(\alpha))$ are non-zero integers.  Further all these norms are bounded by $(n\sqrt{n})^{2^{\pi(n)}}$ (there are $2^{\pi(n)}$ conjugates and each is bounded in size by $\sqrt{1} +\ldots + \sqrt{n} \le n\sqrt{n}$).

Thus $A_n$ can be written as the product of $2^{n-\pi(n)}$ integers each of size at most $(n\sqrt{n})^{2^{\pi(n)}}$, and therefore its largest prime factor is no more than that.